# Break string up

Tags: vb.net, string, substring, indexof

I have a string that has 2 sections broken up by a -.  When I pass this value to my new page I just want the first section.

An example value would be: MS 25 - 25

I just want to show: MS 25

I am looking at IndexOf() and SubString() but I can't find how to get the start of the string and drop the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets7p5.html

Basically the substring method takes 2 parameters.  Start position and length.

In your case, the start position is 0 and length is going to be the position found by the IndexOf method -1.

For example:

```
Dim s as String
Dim result as String

s = "MS 25 - 25"

result = s.SubString(0, s.IndexOf("-")-1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Works perfectly thanks, and vb is 0 based

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Split` function on the hyphen.

```
.Split("-")
```

If you want to stay away from `Split`, you could use `SubString`

```
yourString.Substring(0, yourString.IndexOf("-") - 1)
```

**EDIT**

The above code will fail in the instances where there is no hyphen at all or the hyphen is in the beginning of the string, also when there are no spaces surrounding the hyphen, the full leading substring will not be returned.  Consider using this for safety:

```
Dim pos As Integer
Dim result As String

pos = yourString.IndexOf("-")
If (pos > 0) Then
    result = yourString.Substring(0, pos)
ElseIf (pos = 0) Then
    result = String.Empty
Else
    result = yourString
End If
```

Comment: I was going to use that as a least resort because I'd rather not create a string array just to get the first section. If there is an easier way I'd rather do that.

Comment: I like this for the simple reason that if your string does not contain any hyphens then the first index in the string array is still going to be what you want to show.

Comment: The thing is I know there will ALWAYS be a hyphen because of where I am pulling it from

Comment: It never hurts to do some safety checking.  You might want to check the position from `IndexOf` for > 0.  Else you'll have an error get thrown someday in case always changes.